# click() event jquery

Tags: jquery, events, click

So I have this code which is called in a print_info() function after a AJAX Request;

```
'print_info' : function(message,type) {
        $('.load').hide();
        $('<div>'+message+'</div>').insertAfter('#loader').addClass('autoHideBox '+type).fadeIn("slow").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow", function() { $(this).remove(); });
    },
```

As you may see, the div fades in an out in a matter of seconds, my problem is, even if I'm adding this code :

```
.click(function() { $(this).fadeOut("slow", function() { $(this).remove(); }); } )
```

The div wont fadeOut / remove at all. Can you clear this one ? Because I'm a bit confused regarding this matter.

Regards,
Duluman Edi

---

Later edit:

I got it working with .on("click", callback), but though, fading it out and removing it in the callback just wouldn't work.

So, in order to get it working so you can do whatever you need to do in the callback of the on("click", just add before .on() , stop(true,true).on("click",callback);

```
'print_info' : function(message,type) {
        $('.load').hide();
        $('<div>'+message+'</div>')
            .insertAfter('#loader')
            .addClass('autoHideBox '+type)
            .fadeIn("slow")
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut("slow", function() { $(this).remove(); })
            .on('click', function() {
                $(this).stop(true,true).fadeOut("slow", function() { $(this).remove(); })
            });
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that `.click` is only attachable to elements that were loaded originally on page load.

Since you create the element right then, it isn't being properly attached to the click event. Try instead using `.on('click', callback)` because that can be added to anything that is dynamically created after page load.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Simple callbacks that don't affect div work with on("click",callback), but in order to fix the callback problem, just insert .stop(true,true) before .on("click",callback), edited in the first post so others can see too.

Answer (score 0):

You should use .live('click', function for dynamically added content.

Comment: .live doesn't work, just letting you know that, use .on("click", callback);

Comment: .live doesn't work because it was deprecated and you're probably using the newest version of jquery

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var div = $('<div>This is a test</div>');
     div.insertAfter('#test');
     div.click(function () { 
       div.fadeOut("slow", function() { div.remove(); }); 
     });
   });
```

Comment: Try adding fadeIn / fadeOut before your click function, you'll see it doesn't work. And anyway, you have "document ready function", we are using live div's , that are not added same time with the DOMs.